# How Can I Keep common Struts 2 Jquery Datepicker properties in one place, and get the Struts 2 Jquery datepicker tags to reference these properties?

Tags: jquery, web-applications, struts2, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm currently experimenting with the Struts2 Jquery plugin.

It seems every instance of a datepicker defined in a jsp using this plugin requires its properties set on a tag by tag basis.

For example:

```
<sj:datepicker id="date9" name="date9" 
     label="Show Years only from 2008 until 2012" 
     yearRange="2008:2012" changeYear="true"/>
```

is there any way of defining the above tag as a "2008 datepicker" for example and then for every `<sj:datepicker>` object I want to have the properties of the above `<sj:datepicker>` tag, just refer to "2008 datepicker" to get its properties? In this case its "yearRange" and "changeYear" properties.

I though I could have common datepickers in a jsp of its own and include this jsp but i wouldn't be able to change the id's of the sj tags in this jsp.

Comment: You can (as you said in your last sentence) define a JSP containing a snippet and include it in every page you need. For giving it a different id, you can parametrize it

Comment: can I include the parameter id value when including a jsp page with a datepicker in it? I'd rather not define this value in an action class.

Comment: Like this:<s:include value="myJsp.jsp">
   <s:param name="param1" value="value2" />
   <s:param name="param2" value="value2" />
</s:include> ?

Comment: Exactly, by using #attr to lookup in the page scope: http://javatales.blogspot.it/2010/01/how-to-pass-jspparameter-in-struts-2.html